# Estimate the number of queries per month

Tags: soql, governorlimits

Is there any way to estimate the number of Queries per month in a salesforce instance?

Comment: Why do you need to know this? What's the use case here?

Comment: Hi, We have an custom implementation in a community site to search products. Customer need to get the search count for the products from the community site, Here we can implement a logic in the back end and get the count, but we need a quick way to get this done. Please note customer using only the community site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure queries consumed, I believe your only option is a paid feature, **[`Event Monitoring`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Enabling-Event-Monitoring&language=en_US&type=1)**. Specifically, once activated, it will give you access to the [`EventLogFile`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) object. Once you have access to it, you can find records with the [Search Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_search.htm).

This event type has fields such as:

- `NUM_RESULTS`
- `SEARCH_QUERY`
- `USER_ID`

Obviously there are other fields as well, but even with just `USER_ID` you should be able to get a pretty good idea of who is running how many queries.